# the substring is empty string for initial loop , when everytime the loop runs , new string adds to the substring or it becomes empty string again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, jupyter-notebook, substr

```
def merge_the_tools(string, k):
strings_list = []                     
for i in range(0,len(string),k):               # incrementing the loop by k
    sub = (string[i:i+k])
    substring=''                           # empty substrings
    for x in sub:
        if x not in substring:          # removing the duplicates
            substring = substring + x
    strings_list.append(substring)            # adding it into empty list
print(*strings_list, sep='\n')      # printing the list
```

//This code takes a string breaks into substring based on variable 'k' , then check and remove the duplicates from substrings in an ordered way and print the new substrings.

input : merge_the_tools('AABCAAADA', 3) 
output :AB CA AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're asking whether for each iteration in your outer for-loop the substring-variable will be an empty sting before assigning variables to it. This is the case as you assign the empty string to the variable substring every time you start the loop (i.e after part of string is assigned to sub).

I wil try to go through yout function step by step using string = 'AABCAAADA', k = 3 (I copied the code as many times as necessary for the example and added comments to the code):

```
merge_the_tools('AABCAAADA', 3) #function call will trigger execution of function
strings_list = []                     
for i in range(0,len('AABCAAADA'), 3): #outer loop
# iteration 1: i = 0:
    sub = (string[0:3]) # = 'AAB'
    substring=''
    for x in sub: #inner loop
        # iteration 1.1: x = 'A'
        if 'A' not in substring: #substring is empty
            substring = '' + 'A' # substring = 'A' then go to next x in inner loop
        # iteration 1.2: x = 'A'
        if 'A' not in substring: #substring = 'A' -> condition not fullfilled, go to next x in inner loop
        # iteration 1.3: x = 'B'
        if 'B' not in substring: #substring = 'A'
        substring = 'A' + 'B' # substring = 'AB' -> last x in inner loop -> continue outer loop
    strings_list.append('AB') # strings_list = ['AB'], end of outer loop -> continue with next i of outer loop
# iteration 2: i = 3:
    sub = (string[3:6]) # = 'CAA'
    substring='' #here the empty string is reassigned to substring! 
    for x in sub: #inner loop
        # iteration 2.1: x = 'C'
        if 'C' not in substring: #substring is empty
            substring = '' + 'C' # substring = 'C' then go to next x in inner loop
        # iteration 2.2: x = 'A'
        if 'A' not in substring: #substring = 'C'
        substring = 'C' + 'A' # substring = 'CA' -> go to next x in inner loop
        # iteration 2.3: x = 'A'
        if 'A' not in substring: #substring = 'CA' -> condition not fullfilled, last x in inner loop -> continue outer loop
    strings_list.append('CA') # strings_list = ['AB', 'CA'], end of outer loop -> continue with next i of outer loop
# iteration 3: i = 6:
    sub = (string[6:9]) # = 'ADA'
    substring='' #here the empty string is reassigned to substring! 
    for x in sub: #inner loop
        # iteration 3.1: x = 'A'
        if 'A' not in substring: #substring is empty
            substring = '' + 'A' # substring = 'A' then go to next x in inner loop
        # iteration 3.2: x = 'D'
        if 'D' not in substring: #substring = 'A'
        substring = 'A' + 'D' # substring = 'AD' -> go to next x in inner loop
        # iteration 3.3: x = 'A'
        if 'A' not in substring: #substring = 'AD' -> condition not fullfilled, last x in inner loop -> continue outer loop
    strings_list.append('AD') # strings_list = ['AB', 'CA', 'AD'], end of outer loop -> last i of outer loop -> exit loop

print(*strings_list, sep='\n') #output :AB CA AD
```

Hope that makes things a bit more clear. Also if you are unfamiliar with the concept of loops, there are a lot of good tutorials out there (just google it).

Comment: Yes ,absolutely right, Can you just explain it in more detail , how its happening i,e substring is getting emptied when every time new outer for loop runs  ?

Comment: I will try to explain in more detail for the example you provided:
1. iteration outer loop: i=0 -> sub=string[0:3]='AAB', substring='' -> inner loop: 1.1 x='A' -> not in substring? yes -> substring = '' + 'A' = 'A' -> 1.2 x='A' ->not in substring? no -> 1.3 x='B' -> not in substring? yes -> substring='A'+'B'='AB' -> inner loop done -> strings_list.append('AB') -> 2. Iteration outer loop: i=3 -> sub=string[3:6]='CAA', substring='' **here empty string is reassigned to substring** -> inner loop as before but with 'CAA' -> 3. Iteration outer loop: i=6 -> sub=string[6:9]='ADA', substring='' -> ...

Comment: I've just edited my previous answer including the comment above.

Comment: Thankyou buddy , I really appreciate the way you have explained , so everything in the loop gets back to original state once a new loop runs.Its automatically happening , I mean like when we reassign a value to a variable it keeps updating the value for the same variable again , . so its not true in case of loops ,as it automatically makes the variable empty when a new loop runs ?

Comment: Well, a for loop loops back over the same block of code again and again for the number of times specified (in your case 3 times). Variables are not automatically emptied when a new loop runs. It has to be specified in the loop that you want them to be empty when the loop starts (like `substring =''` does).